# How to assign multiple classes to an HTML container?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to assign multiple classes to a single `HTML` container?

Something like:

```
<article class="column, wrapper">
```

Comment: What problem do you have now? Any way that was the solution to this problem. Any other problem may depend on several factors.

Comment: Though this is doable, I usually use nested containers with CSS inheritance. It is much prettier, and usually more useful.

Comment: If you are still having an issue after removal of the comma I suggest looking at the guidance on [why rules don't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Common_CSS_Questions#Style_rules_that_don.27t_work). I've found the most common speed-bump for me is the situation described there as "Use of a shorthand poperty" (i.e., implictly reverting to a default value)

Answer (score 677):

Just remove the comma like this:

```
<article class="column wrapper">
```

Comment: <article class="class1 class2 ... classN">

Comment: Wierd its space instead of commas. But yeah thanks for the answer

Answer (score 226):

From the standard

> 7.5.2 Element identifiers: the id and class attributes
>
> Attribute definitions
>
> id = name [CS]
>   This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name
>   must be unique in a document.
>
> class = cdata-list [CS]
>   This attribute
>   assigns a class name or set of class names to an element. Any number
>   of elements may be assigned the same class name or names. Multiple
>   class names must be separated by white space characters.

Yes, just put a space between them.

```
<article class="column wrapper">
```

Of course, there are many things you can do with CSS inheritance. Here is an [article for further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

Comment: How should a browser be expected to react if an element is assigned to multiple classes that set different values for the same attributes. Is there some order of precedence for that?

Comment: @EternallyCurious The attributes are aggregated by the browser, so this behavior will be non-deterministic.

Comment: @JonathanHenson: no, it's not. In case of tied specificity, the rule that occurs later in the CSS wins.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz the later listed CSS class (what I was hoping for when I tested this), or later in all of the CSS files? Because the former most certainly does not work in the browsers I tested in, while I have tested the latter hypothesis.

Comment: @JonathanHenson: According to [CSS 2.1 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order), "if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself." So it is CSS declaration order. The names in the class attribute have no specified order, since `.foo` is syntactic sugar for `[class ~=  foo]` [ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html), "`foo` is a word in the `class` attribute".

Comment: **Update:** In the [current HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/), as of 2021, a `class` is known as one of many [attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attributes-3). Class names are assigned as a set of ["space-separated tokens”](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#space-separated-tokens). The class names are separated by [“ASCII whitespace”](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#ascii-whitespace) which is defined as: U+0009 TAB, U+000A LF, U+000C FF, U+000D CR, or U+0020 SPACE.

Answer (score 26):

To assign **multiple classes** to an **html element**, include both class names within the quotations of the class attribute and have them separated by a space:

```
<article class="column wrapper">
```

In the above example, `column` and `wrapper` are two separate css classes, and both of their properties will be applied to the `article` element.

Comment: what has this answer different from the previous?

Answer (score -12):

you need to put a dot between the class like

class="column.wrapper">

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should one use a dot there, instead of a space?