# jQuery need automatically fill only one input field (row) based on value in other field (autocomplete); all other fields must remain unchanged

Tags: javascript, jquery

This http://af-design.com/blog/2010/05/12/using-jquery-uis-autocomplete-to-populate-a-form/ script automatically fills state and zip, based on city.

There is one row with id like id="city". If I want additional rows, I must use something like id="city1", id="city2" etc.

In javascript code then may use something like

`$("#city").val(ui.item.city);`

`$("#city1").val(ui.item.city1);`

This is not ok, if I have many rows.

So I trying to change. Below is changed code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ac_config = {
source: "__demo_cities.php",
select: function(event, ui){
$('[id^="city"]').val(ui.item.city);
$('[id^="state"]').val(ui.item.state);
$('[id^="zip"]').val(ui.item.zip);
},
minLength:1
};
$('[id^="city"]').autocomplete(ac_config);
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="city[]" id="city" value="" />
<input type="text" name="state[]" id="state" value="" />
<input type="text" name="zip[]" id="zip" value="" />

<br>
<input type="text" name="city[]" id="city1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="state[]" id="state1" value="" />
<input type="text" name="zip[]" id="zip1" value="" />
```

If I enter something in `city` script automatically fills `id="state"`, `id="zip"` (that is ok), but it also automatically fills `id="city1"`, `id="state1"` and `id="zip1"` (that is not necessary).

Need behavior: if enter something in `id="city"`, automatically fills only `id="state"` and `id="zip"` and all other fields remains blank/unchanged; if enter in `id="city1"`, automatically fills only `id="state"` and `id="zip"` and all other fields remains blank/unchanged.

Based on @JNF advice there is one code that works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ac_config = {
source: "__demo_cities.php",
select: function(event, ui){
$(this).closest(".myForm").find('[id^="city"]').val(ui.item.city);
$(this).closest(".myForm").find('[id^="state"]').val(ui.item.state);
$(this).closest(".myForm").find('[id^="zip"]').val(ui.item.zip);
},
minLength:1
};
$('[id^="city"]').autocomplete(ac_config);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[id^="city"]` selector you're using means "anything starting with city", so it affects `city1` as well. The same with the rest of them.

I would wrap them in another element, something like this:

```
<span class="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="city[]" id="city" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="state[]" id="state" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="zip[]" id="zip" value="" />
</span>
<span class="myForm">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="city[]" id="city1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="state[]" id="state1" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="zip[]" id="zip1" value="" />
</span>
```

Then, in jQuery something like

```
$(this).closest(".myForm").find("[id^=state]") etc...
```

Comment: Changed code to 
$(this).closest(".myForm").find("#city").val(ui.item.city);
$(this).closest(".myForm").find("#state").val(ui.item.state);
$(this).closest(".myForm").find("#zip").val(ui.item.zip);
But what to do with $('[id^="city"]').autocomplete(ac_config); ?
Now only the first row works. 
If $('[id^="city"]').autocomplete(ac_config); change to $(this).closest(".myForm").find("#city").autocomplete(ac_config); then does not work at all

Comment: You need to change the HTML as well, of course. Also, Keep the code as `[id^=city]`, not `#city`. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would assign classes to your inputs, it's faster to select them by class, then by substring in their IDs:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="city" name="city[]" id="city0" value="" />
<input type="text" class="state" name="state[]" id="state0" value="" />
<input type="text" class="zip" name="zip[]" id="zip0" value="" />

<br>
<input type="text" class="city" name="city[]" id="city1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="state" name="state[]" id="state1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="zip" name="zip[]" id="zip1" value="" />
```

JavaScript

```
$( ".city" ).change(function(e) {
var anIDString=this.id;
anIDString = anIDString.replace('city','zip');
$('#'+anIDString).val('This one changed!');
}
);
```

Comment: Thank you. unfortunately class cannot be used in my case. Because, class names I need like city, city1, city2 etc.

Comment: You do realise, that you can assign several classes to HTML element, and instead of "city" for this purpose you may use "something_totally_different"?

Comment: You mean like class="city city_otherclass"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container. I did not know it... Thank you. Will try

Comment: Well, repeating "city" twice is not a good thing to do, but otherwise - you got an idea.

Comment: there is _ i mean city_otherclass. Because of row below the underscore sign is not visible