# Can I apply more than one CSS3 class to an element?

Tags: html, css

I'm reading different opinions on this. Is this allowed in <s>CSS</s> HTML5:

`<div class="one-class another-class">...`

to apply the properties of both `one-class` and `another-class` to the element?

---

*Re the downvote: yes, I tried it, and it does work. But that doesn't mean it's good practice. It could be deprecated for instance.*

Comment: This isn't CSS3, or CSS for that matter. It's HTML.

Comment: you could have tried it...

Comment: #Philipp: Yes, I tried it and it works. But it could be deprecated, or anything. (Is the downvote yours?)

Comment: It's a good question. +1 to cancel the unjustified downvote. (Could indeed be for the reason Philipp mentions)

Comment: That reason was given by the asker, @Federico :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assign multiple classes to an HTML container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container)

Comment: This was closed as **OFF TOPIC**???? WTF?

Comment: a perfectly good question, helped me today in 2022, only SO can shut something like this down and have demotivating comments, sigh. +1 from me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is allowed.

The `class` attribute according to the HTML specification:

> "This attribute assigns a class name or set of class names to an
>   element. Any number of elements may be assigned the same class name or
>   names. Multiple class names must be separated by white space
>   characters."

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 4):

Yes its possible. You can add multiple class names to class attribute of any element. Also take in account that the different properties of different classes used in class attribute will applied to the element.

```
.class1{
    color: red;
 }
.class2{
    font-weight: bold;
 }

<div class="class1 class2">My Text</div>
```

The output  contains text "My Text" will be displayed in bold and red color.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To select with both:

```
.one-class.another-class {
    color:red;
}
```

It's very common to extend the code like that, e.g. by defining a `button` class, and `button-important` class, then using:

```
<div class='button button-important'></div>
```

to get both styles together.