# Multiple Class Naming Convention

Tags: html, css

Recently i have been looking into Plugins and i keep seeing class names such as

```
  <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
    <div class="title">Slide 2</div>
    <p>Keep swiping</p>
  </div>
```

It gets confusing when i am trying to modify the css files, I wanted to understand this class naming convention.

What does class="swiper-slide red-slide" mean? Does it mean that div has class attribute = "swiper-slide" and = "red-slide" ?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what it means. It has both `swiper-slide` and `red-slide` classes.

Comment: Yes, Space separated classes, for assigning multiple classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container

Yes, read about it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a HTML element can have multiple classes.

```
<div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
```

means, that you can access the element with the class ".swiper-slide" and also ".red-slide".
Of course, this does not work with IDs.

Answer (score 1):

> **Class.**
>   This attribute is a space-separated list of the classes of the element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#class