# Div is not changing position no matter what I do

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I am trying to change the position of the div "home_square" but when I do it just stays in the same spot please help.

```
<div class="nav_square" class="home_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="specials_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="jobs_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="league_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="contact_square"></div>
<!--POSITION SAFE NAV SQUARES-->
        <div class="nav_square" class="safe_nav_squares" class="home_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="safe_nav_squares" class="specials_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="safe_nav_squares" class="jobs_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="safe_nav_squares" class="league_square"></div>
        <div class="nav_square" class="safe_nav_squares" class="contact_square"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav_square {
    background-color:green;
    width:100px;
    height:2px;
    z-index:22;
}
.home_square {
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
.safe_nav_squares {
    background-color:black;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

The safe nav squares are just so when I add my javascript and make the nav squares disappear that the other elements on the page will not change position.

Comment: You have two (even three on some)  `class` attributes. That's a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try with this code....

```
<div class="nav_square home_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square specials_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square jobs_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square league_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square contact_square"></div>
    <!--POSITION SAFE NAV SQUARES-->
            <div class="nav_square safe_nav_squares home_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square safe_nav_squares specials_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square safe_nav_squares jobs_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square safe_nav_squares league_square"></div>
            <div class="nav_square safe_nav_squares contact_square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, classes must be separated by spaces, all within the same attribute. When you do this, also keep in mind that the order matters - rules from *later* classes always override *earlier* ones.

**Example:**

```
<div class="foo blah">
    I have two classes, foo and blah. When they disagree, blah wins.
</div>
```

Here is a tutorial that describes it in more detail:
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-element.html

Here is a useful Stack Overflow question:
[How to assign multiple classes to an HTML container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container)