# How can I assign multiple classes to an image?

Tags: css, html

I want my img element to be both rounded and responsive. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
<img src = "someimage.jpg" class = "img-rounded" class = "img-responsive"/>
```

Comment: Using Bootstrap is probably the best option for you.

Comment: But doesn't it only allow only one class per image file. Can I apply two different classes at the same time? If so, how?

Comment: Uhm. `class="img-rounded img-responsive foobar etc"`.

Comment: Thank you!! Works like magic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign multiple classes to an HTML container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container)

Answer (score 5):

Put both in one `class` attribute with a space in between

```
<img src="someimage.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
```