# Using Bootstrap CSS. Have an issue - I change my class name and it no longer works

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap CSS style:

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
   color: #428bca;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
 }
```

I have the MVC 5 HTML as:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new {
 @class = "active" })</li>
```

The CSS performs perfectly.

I change the class name from "active" to "xyz" or anything for that matter and it does not work any longer. I do the change in both places, the HTML and CSS.

When I do an inspect, the rule no longer appears as it does when the class name is "active".

Why?

Comment: Whatever that is it's not plain HTML

Comment: It's an MVC app and it is valid. It works fine when I name the class - "active".

Comment: Your two styles (`color` and `background`) only apply when the element has class `active`. That's what `.active` means in your stylesheet.

Comment: I know...but now I want to change the name from active to something else and it no longer works. It should as it's just a class name.

Comment: Then you should update the tags on your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using bootstrap for your navigation bar and in that case there is some predefined classes which has been styled by css. So you cannot put any random class.

For other classes you can refer:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Comment: So if I am using Bootstrap, i can't use custom class names? I need custom class names as I have 3 links and can't name all of them "active". They need to be unique.

Comment: you can use custom class name but you need to define those classes in your css file

Comment: you can also use concept of multiple class like one defined in bootstrap and other one in your css file  like <class="active xyx">

Comment: 2nd comment: That is what I was doing. I changed "active" to "xyz" in the both the CSS file and the HTML. But it did not work.

Comment: I just now tried using Ids and it works. In the HTML I changed class to id and the CSS too and it works.  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > #movielink {
    color: #428bca !important;
    background-color: #e7e7e7 !important;
}      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { id = "homelink" })</li>

Comment: I did: .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a.xyz{
   color: #428bca;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
 }

Comment: And...the HTML:  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new {
 @class = "xyz" })</li>

Comment: yes it will work as you have created id and defined it. if you want to keep it to class only or assign multiple class you can refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container

Answer (score 0):

Your css rule says that the element must have the classname *active* and be an *a* element, inside an *li* element inside an *navbar-nav* class named element.

So when you change the classname target to something else, the rule does no longer apply

Comment: But I do change it in BOTH places. I think the reply regarding that I am using Bootstrap might be the problem.