# Element admin not allowed as child of element span in this context

Tags: html, wordpress

I implemented author vcard in my wordpress single post fine with the following code:

```
<span class="vcard author"><span class="fn"> Written by: <Admin rel="author"><?php the_author() ?> </Admin> </span></span>
```

But when i check the web page with w3c validator it gives the error:

> Element admin not allowed as child of element span in this context.
>   (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

What should i change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nesting error, basically it means that the validator does not comprehend the structure you've made either try to remove the nesting of admin or remove the `<Admin>` all together.

Here's some info:

[How to fix: Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (suppressing further errors from this subtree.)](http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/element-x-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-y-in-this-context-suppressing-further-errors-from-this-subtree/element-div-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-ul-in-this-context-suppressing-further-errors-from-this-subtree/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am a rookie so I need more elaboration. How can i remove the nesting of admin? Is there any replacement?

Comment: As DIDIx13 said `<Admin>` isnt a HTML tag, so maybe the error is there. If you want to define the  author as a value you can use pretty much any HTML5 tag, just include the `rel="author"` inside it. Try this code `<span class="vcard author fn"> Written by: <p rel="author"><?php the_author() ?> </p> </span>`

Answer (score 0):

1. `<Admin>` doesn't exist in HTML, you should remove it.

You can replace it with a [`<p>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_p.asp) who defines a paragraph.

---

2. You have two `<span>` following each other with different classes. Is it intended?

[You can use multiple classes in one tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8722176/8303093): `<span class="fn vcard author">`

---

<sup>[Sources](http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/element-x-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-y-in-this-context-suppressing-further-errors-from-this-subtree/element-div-not-allowed-as-child-of-element-ul-in-this-context-suppressing-further-errors-from-this-subtree/)</sup>