# How can I select an element based on an explicit match in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are two elements : `<div class = "abc def">` and `<div class = "abc">`

I want to select the latter.

My code is

```
soup.find('div', {'class':'abc'})
```

However it select the former.

What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The former element has two classes:  and  (see e.g. [How to assign multiple classes to an HTML container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container)), so BeautifulSoup correctly points at it when using `find()`.

In order to point to the second you should use `findAll` - which returns a list - and extract the second element:

```
soup.findAll('div', {'class':'abc'})[1]
```

Comment: If you mean the last element of a list, you just type `listname[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

From [Official doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) :

> You can also search for the **exact string value** of the class attribute:
>
> ```
> css_soup.find_all("p", class_="body strikeout")
> # [<p class="body strikeout"></p>]
> ```

```
soup.find_all("div", class_="abc")
```

Comment: It will select both.

Answer (score 0):

Try `:nth-of-type(2)` or `:nth-child(2)` with css selector.

```
print(soup.select_one('.abc:nth-of-type(2)'))
```

**Example**:

```
html='''<div class = "abc def"></div>
        <div class = "abc"></div>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('.abc:nth-of-type(2)'))
```

---

**Edited:**

```
print(soup.select_one('.abc:not(.def)'))
```

Comment: It returns None.

Comment: @Chan : Please post your html Structure.Is your html look like my given example then it should work.If Not can you post Html?

Comment: @Chan : please check the Edited answer.Hope this will help.

Comment: It still returns None.

Answer (score 0):

To get an exact class match, you can use the following function lambda expression as filter.

```
 soup.find_all(lambda x: x.name == 'div' and ''.join(x.get('class', list())) == 'abc')
```

You can also wrap this in a function if you want. `''.join(x.get('class', list())) == 'abc'` joins a the classes (if available) and checks if it is equal to `'abc'`.

Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div class = "abc def"></div>
<div class = "abc"></div>
<div></div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(
    soup.find_all(
        lambda x: x.name == 'div' and ''.join(x.get('class', list())) == 'abc'
    )
)
```

Output

```
[<div class="abc"></div>]
```

Ref:

- [Function as filter - BeautifulSoup Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function)