# Changing display from block to none for multiple textareas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to figure out how to make a text area disappear while another one will appear instead.

I have no knowledge of javascript and I have just started learning the basics of HTML and CSS, is there a chance anyone from the forum can help me out or maybe guide me to the correct path.

I'm attaching the part of the code, to make it more clear.

When you click on "2.svg" it should change the "textarea.one's and three's" "display: block;" into "display: none;"

When you click on "3.svg" it should change the "textarea.two's and one's" "display: block;" into "display: none;"

When you click on "1.svg" it should change the "textarea.two's and three's" "display: block;" into "display: none;"

I hope this explanation is clear enough, I'm also not sure if I'm allowed to ask to provide full code on this forum without preparing anything on my own.

Thank you in advance to whoever will read this!

```
<div>
      <img id="header1" src="/1.svg" alt="Open Menu" class="menu">
      <img id="header1" src="/2.svg" alt="Open Menu" class="menu">
      <img id="header1" src="/3.svg" alt="Open Menu" class="menu">
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="one" id="myInput" name="myInput" readonly>
Line one
Line two
Line three</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="two" id="myInput" name="myInput" readonly>
Line four
Line five
Line six</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="three" id="myInput" name="myInput" readonly>
Line seven
Line eight
Line nine</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

In order to change an element's display property, you can access it like this:

```
document.querySelector("myelement").style.display = "theValueIWant";
```

Mind the different [selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Now, what you want is when we click 2.svg to change textarea one and three's diplay property from block to none. First select these using `document.querySelector("textarea.one")` and then change the value: `document.querySelector("textarea.one").style.display = "none";`
Now, to call this javascript you need an event. You can use the onClick one. Simply

```
 <img id="header1" onClick="document.querySelector('textarea.one').style.display = 'none';" src="/1.svg" alt="Open Menu" class="menu">
```

would change the display property of the textarea.one element on click.

**Method I** In order to call multiple elements, what I suggest is adding one more class to the two elements that you are going to hide, and the simply use the above code with changing the class. E.g., to `textarea` one and three [add class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container) `hideOne` and then hide the element with `document.querySelector("hideOne").style.display = "none";`

**Method II** Another way you can accomplish this, is by creating a function that would hide the two components. Create a script tag and then use the above selector to hide the two elements:

```
<script>
function hide1(){
document.querySelector('textarea.one').style.display = "none"
document.querySelector('textarea.three').style.display = "none"
}
</script>
```

Then call the function by inserting into the element to be clicked(your svg): `onClick="hide1()"`

That's it!

Comment: Hi, this advice was very helpful, I was able to do it with the steps you have sent.

Comment: Additionally, let me know if you can assist me further. If I open the page it will display "textarea.one" as the first option. I would like to know is there a way to change this, so through previous pages, I open this page, but it shows "textarea.two" instead?

Comment: Hi, If you have found my response useful consider approving the answer and upvoting it(helps me), which would improve the quality of the threat and allow for other people having similar issues find quality answers faster. Regarding the second question, I am a bit confused by what you mean. You want only one textarea to show on page load? Maybe open a new question where you can showcase the problem in more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already created another question and trying to resolve it there. It probably is easier to do it through a new topic.

Comment: I have approved and upvoted your answer, thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

The following is a very short way of achieving the same without jQuery.

It is not as easy to read as the jQuery based solution but contains certain elements that might be interesting to you too:

1. I used a "delegated event attachment" which means I attached the click event handler to the parent element (the first div in the document) of the three `<img>` elements. Doing it this way keeps the document "fast" and makes it easily extendable by further elements.
2. I identify the clicked image by its `id` attribute: only if the clicked element has the `tagName==="DIV"` and its `id` starts with "header", I will take the remaining (`id`-string - 1) as the index to look-up the class name `c` in the `cls` array.
3. In the `txtas.forEach()` loop I will then make the `<textarea>` containing `c` in its `classList` visible, while all others will be hidden.

```js
const cls=["one","two","three"],
      txtas=document.getElementsByName("myInput");
document.querySelector("div").onclick=ev=>{ let el=ev.target;
  if(el.tagName==="IMG"&&el.id.substr(0,6)==="header"){
    let c=cls[el.id.substr(6)-1];
    txtas.forEach(t=>t.style.display=t.classList.contains(c)?"":"none");
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
      <img id="header1" src="/1.svg" alt="first" class="menu">
      <img id="header2" src="/2.svg" alt="second" class="menu">
      <img id="header3" src="/3.svg" alt="third" class="menu">
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="one" name="myInput" readonly>
Line one
Line two
Line three</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="two" name="myInput" readonly>
Line four
Line five
Line six</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="three" name="myInput" readonly>
Line seven
Line eight
Line nine</textarea>
</div>
```

I removed the `id` attributes from your `<textarea>` elements as they would have been dupes. The script works very well without them.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible with just `CSS` but so easy with `JQuery` (which I think would be easier fo you to start as the semantic is much more read friendly for begginers than pure `javascript`)

like this:

```js
$("#header1").click(function(){
  $(".two").hide();
  $(".three").hide();
  $(".one").show();
});
$("#header2").click(function(){
  $(".one").hide();
  $(".three").hide();
  $(".two").show();
});
$("#header3").click(function(){
  $(".one").hide();
  $(".two").hide();
  $(".three").show();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
      <img id="header1" src="/1.svg" alt="Open Menu" class="menu">
      <img id="header2" src="/2.svg" alt="Open Menu" class="menu">
      <img id="header3" src="/3.svg" alt="Open Menu" class="menu">
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="one" id="myInput" name="myInput" readonly>
Line one
Line two
Line three</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="two" id="myInput" name="myInput" readonly>
Line four
Line five
Line six</textarea>
</div>

<div class="textniz">
  <textarea class="three" id="myInput" name="myInput" readonly>
Line seven
Line eight
Line nine</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot to add in my request, how do I make only one of three visible on the initial page? Instead of all three together?

Comment: Just add `style="display:none;` to the div you want to hide

Answer (score 0):

So as per your question, if it is just a quick switch and you want only one view to be active, it's better and easy to use jQuery because it is very direct, @Alvaro has already shared the quick code snippet. It's very easy to play around with jQuery.

Disclaimer: It makes your life so easy that if in case you try to learn a full seasoned framework, then there will be a long workaround. But get started with jQuery. You'll find it very interactive.

Happy Coding :)