# how to add two classes in tailwind FOR TARGETING IT IN JS

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

how to give two classes in tailwind, in tailwind we write styling inside class attribute, what if if want to
add extra class in it so that i can target it in JS because of course i can't target it with styling

```
 <i class="fa-solid fa-play fa-2xl" style="color: #fcfcfc;" class="Mexico">
```

Comment: Doesn't this work `class="fa-solid fa-play fa-2xl your-custom-class"`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722163/how-to-assign-multiple-classes-to-an-html-container

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't add multiple `class` attributes, since a browser will simply ignore the second one.

You custom class would have to just go in the `class` attribute alongside your other classes and then target it with [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)

```js
const elems = document.getElementsByClassName("Mexico");
console.log(elems)
```

```html
<i class="fa-solid fa-play fa-2xl Mexico" style="color: #fcfcfc;">Mexico</i>
```

Alternatively, you could add a custom attribute:
(typically done with `data-...` [See MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) )

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-custom="mexico"]`);
console.log(elems)
```

```html
<i class="fa-solid fa-play fa-2xl" data-custom="mexico" style="color: #fcfcfc;">Mexico</i>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `querySelector`?

Comment: Possibly yes, though I don't know the performance implications of each method